# C# - How to assign different lines of File.ReadAllText to individual variables?

Tags: c#, variables

What I've got is a text file with some (hypothetical) students and their attendance.

Looks like this:

```
Stud1
LOOOALLOOAAL
Stud2
OOOOOOOAOOOO
Stud3
LLLLOOOOALLA
```

So what I want to do, is assign say `Stud1` to show `Stud1: LOOOALLOOAAL` etc etc.

Any ideas?

Comment: _"Any ideas?"_ - no idea what you are talking about.  Please provide more info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

actually your post is kind of "unclear" to readers but I did get your point regarding reading lines from text to variables

I suggest you use File.ReadAllLines, then format your text with each values separated per line

so it goes like this

**Source.txt**

```
LOOOALLOOAAL
OOOOOOOAOOOO
LLLLOOOOALLA
```

then your line of code will be

```
string[] students = File.ReadAllLines("Source.txt");
```

thus the values would be

```
students[0] = LOOOALLOOAAL
students[1] = OOOOOOOAOOOO
students[2] = LLLLOOOOALLA
```

the code **File.ReadAllLines()** gets every line of text from your source file until it reaches the endline and stores it into an array of string. if you needed your values for calculations, then you'll need to parse such values

I just showed you how to get values from text to variables. how you show them as output will be on you.

Comment: and next time please use discrete values not "LOOOALLOOAAL"

Comment: Sorry - first time with this website and I'm very new to C#, but thanks ever so much for your help!